# error on importing of eneter in java tcp

Tags: java, android, tcpserver

I am working on a tcp server communicator and I am using the coding found on this [website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340714/Android-How-to-communicate-with-NET-application-vi). I am getting errors in the import of the eneters, the first 5 imports. It says that it cannot be resolved. What do I do to get these imports?

```
import eneter.messaging.diagnostic.EneterTrace;
import eneter.messaging.endpoints.typedmessages.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.messagingsystembase.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.tcpmessagingsystem.TcpMessagingSystemFactory;
import eneter.net.system.EventHandler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity extends Activity {
    // Request message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public static class MyRequest {
        public String Text;
    }

    // Response message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public static class MyResponse {
        public int Length;
    }

    // UI controls
    private Handler myRefresh = new Handler();
    private EditText myMessageTextEditText;
    private EditText myResponseEditText;
    private Button mySendRequestBtn;

    // Sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving MyResponse.
    private IDuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest> mySender;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tcp_server);

        // Get UI widgets.
        myMessageTextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageTextEditText);
        myResponseEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageLengthEditText);
        mySendRequestBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendRequestBtn);

        // Subscribe to handle the button click.
        mySendRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(myOnSendRequestClickHandler);

        try {
            openConnection();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            EneterTrace.error("Open connection failed.", err);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop listening to response messages.
        mySender.detachDuplexOutputChannel();
    }

    private void openConnection() throws Exception {
        // Create sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving
        // MyResponse
        IDuplexTypedMessagesFactory aSenderFactory = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
        mySender = aSenderFactory.createDuplexTypedMessageSender(
                MyResponse.class, MyRequest.class);

        // Subscribe to receive response messages.
        mySender.responseReceived().subscribe(myOnResponseHandler);

        // Create TCP messaging for the communication.
        // Note: 10.0.2.2 is a special alias to the loopback (127.0.0.1)
        // on the development machine
        IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();
        IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel = aMessaging
                .createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://10.0.2.2:8060/");

        // Attach the output channel to the sender and be able to send
        // messages and receive responses.
        mySender.attachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);
    }

    private void onSendRequest(View v) {
        // Create the request message.
        MyRequest aRequestMsg = new MyRequest();
        aRequestMsg.Text = myMessageTextEditText.getText().toString();

        // Send the request message.
        try {
            mySender.sendRequestMessage(aRequestMsg);
        } catch (Exception err) {
            EneterTrace.error("Sending the message failed.", err);
        }
    }

    private void onResponseReceived(Object sender,
            final TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e) {
        // Display the result - returned number of characters.
        // Note: Marshal displaying to the correct UI thread.
        myRefresh.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myResponseEditText.setText(Integer.toString(e
                        .getResponseMessage().Length));
            }
        });
    }

    private EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>> myOnResponseHandler

    = new EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Object sender,
                TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e) {
            onResponseReceived(sender, e);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener myOnSendRequestClickHandler = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSendRequest(v);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you simply copy-pasted the code on the website, or also downloaded and included the code in your project?  There's a "get source code" link at the top of the page.

If you don't have the source with the names you try to import in your project, you can't call them.  They are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Sam Bevins how you resolve that problem please share it

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the jar files from the eneter website. After doing this I was able to change my build path and eclipse was able to understand the imports.